# Authentication User in Django Class Based Views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-decorators

I'm trying to refactor my django project. 
Therefore I want to refactor from:

```
    @api_view([GET, POST])
    @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, VehiclePermissions, ))
    def inactive_vehicle_view(request):

        if request.method == "GET":
            con = CBaseUtil.get_prod_instance()
            vehicle_bo = VehicleBO()
            dongle_dao = OBDDongleDAO(con)

            since_days = int(request.GET.get("since", 28))

            vehicles = vehicle_bo.find_vehicles_by_user_context(request.user.details)

            return Response(vehicles, status=status_code, headers=get_headers(request))
```

To a class based view like this:

```
class InactiveVehicleView(View):

    @authentication_classes((BasicAuthentication, WebsiteAuthentication))
    @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, VehiclePermissions, ))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(InactiveVehicleView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        con = CBaseUtil.get_prod_instance()
        vehicle_bo = VehicleBO()
        dongle_dao = OBDDongleDAO(con)

        since_days = int(request.GET.get("since", 28))

        vehicles = vehicle_bo.find_vehicles_by_user_context(request.user.details)

        return Response(vehicles, status=status_code, headers=get_headers(request))
```

The issue I'm facing is that I can't get the user details like in the old version by request.user.details as the WSGI-Request does not contain an attribute user. I guess I did something wrong with the decorators but I can't figure it out.

FYI the view is mapped in the urls like this:

```
url(r'^vehicles/inactive/?$', InactiveVehicleView.as_view())
```

Does anyone have an idea what I did wrong with the authentication and/or the decorators?

Comment: Right, I also tried putting the api_view decorator two, but this doesn't help any matters.

Comment: Maybe this is what you need https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class

Comment: @danielcorreia I already tried to implement following the class based view documentation. But there is no hint how to use the authentication_classes and permission_classes decorator and how to get the data of the authenticated user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Django Rest Framework Authentication Docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme), your view should subclass `APIView`, and set `authentication_classes` and `permission_classes` as attributes instead of using the decorators.

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class InactiveVehicleView(APIView):

    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication, WebsiteAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, VehiclePermissions)

    def get(self, request):
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. Should have checked in the docks too, in addition to the class based tutorial.